# If a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions converges to a function $f$ on $S$ (a subset of real numbers), then $f$ is integrable on $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions converges to a function $f$ on $S$ (a subset of real numbers), then $f$ is integrable on $S$.

i know that it is true for uniform convergence is it true for even converges?

Comment: This question seems to be missing a lot of context and details. Could you expand a bit? What is $S$? Are there any requirements on teh $f_n$?

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ as $\{r_{1},r_{2},...\}$, let $f_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\chi_{\{r_{k}\}}$, then $f_{n}\rightarrow\chi_{{\bf{Q}}\cap[0,1]}$ which the latter is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: This is one of the main reasons why the Lebesgue integral is important. Contrary to the Riemann integral, the space of functions integrable in the sense of Lebesgue is a complete space.